# Why does vim open network connections to a process owned by another user?

Tags: linux, vim

I just noticed something *really* weird...

When I run `lsof` of my vim process I see connections to port 6013 of a process owned by another local user. I wonder where they might come from. I trust the system and that other user. I don't expect any form of attack. Rather a PEBKAC-style error on my behalf.

I've been looking through my vimrc, even grepped through [my vimfiles](https://github.com/exhuma/vimfiles) looking for "6013" but could not find any matches.

I am at a loss to look where they might come from...

Something to note is that the "remote" process is the sshd process of that other user.

lsof output (in total 513 lines):

```
vim     25955 michel    3u  IPv6 106403503      0t0  TCP localhost:36886->localhost:6010 (ESTABLISHED)
vim     32539 michel    3u  IPv6 106429306      0t0  TCP localhost:42422->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    4u  IPv6 106429312      0t0  TCP localhost:42423->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    5u  IPv6 106429316      0t0  TCP localhost:42424->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    6u  IPv6 106429320      0t0  TCP localhost:42425->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    7u  IPv6 106429324      0t0  TCP localhost:42426->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    8u  IPv6 106429330      0t0  TCP localhost:42427->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel    9u  IPv6 106429334      0t0  TCP localhost:42428->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel   10u  IPv6 106429338      0t0  TCP localhost:42429->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel   11u  IPv6 106429344      0t0  TCP localhost:42430->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
vim     32539 michel   12u  IPv6 106451243      0t0  TCP localhost:42695->localhost:6013 (CLOSE_WAIT)
[snip]
```

Current list of plugins:

```
Plugin 'Jinja'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'NrrwRgn'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'gitv'
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'molokai'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'unimpaired.vim'
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
```

Looking at the output of `sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 6013`, I see this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6013          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2285/sshd: franky@n
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6013                :::*                    LISTEN      2285/sshd: franky@n
```

So the process owned by me (michel), opens a TCP connection to a process owned by `franky`.

I also tried to run vim without vimrc, using `vim -u NONE`, but the network connections still appear...

Comment: what plugins to you use?

Comment: Yes, there's a very high chance of PEBKAC. You should add the output of `$ lsof | grep -i vim` to your question.

Comment: My bad... added lsof output and list of plugins to the question.

Comment: Are you "michel" or is it that other user?

Comment: Hmm yes, apparently you are Michel.

Comment: yes. that's me. If I look what process is listening on 6013, it shows a process from someone else. I'll update the question in a second.

Comment: I also tried to run without rc-file (added to the end of the question). The problem still persists, even without rc-file. This is becoming increasingly bizarre...

Comment: Port 6013 would correspond to X11 display `localhost:13`. On franky's end this is probably just a normal X11 forwarding socket created by `ssh -X`. Your vim might be trying to connect to it because you have a bad `DISPLAY` environment variable (assuming the vim in question is X11-enabled).

Answer (score 0):

In the mean-time, I came to the same comclusion as @Wumpus: Port `6013` is a port related to X11 forwarding. And in the end it turned out to be a problem with my `~/.Xauthority`. I simply removed this file and re-connected to the remote host which solved the problem.

It might also have been a bad `$DISPLAY` variable. But I read @Wumpus's comment only after I removed my `~/.Xauthority` file, so I cannot his theory.